# To setup 3 2-node FCI's, what is the basis to decide whether to go for 3 2-node WSFC versus 1 6-node WSFC?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, clustering

I want to setup 3 2-node FCI's

To do this I can either setup 3 2-node WSFC

Or 1 6-node WSFC

Either ways, there will be 1 file share witness in each WSFC.

What is the basis to decide between the above 2 options?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to setup 3 2-node FCI's

> What is the basis to decide between the above 2 options?

Since you've already decided that your setup will be 2 nodes each, it's personal preference at this point. There are some idiosyncrasies with two node clusters, but generally if they all serve the same application then putting them together makes sense. If they don't all server the same application or set of applications, then I wouldn't put them together, for administrative and agility purposes. However, again, preference.

Comment: When I say 2 node I mean 2node+1file share. I will edit the question to say so if that helps.

Comment: There are still some oddities with 2 node clusters (whether FCI or AG) that only occur with two nodes, mostly around quorum which is too much to explain on a forum in length.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the basis to decide between the above 2 options?

Really the choice is between 3 2-node clusters and 1 4-node cluster.

Instead of having a passive node for *each* active node, you can use a single passive node for the whole cluster.

This is typically called an N+1 cluster, or here a 3+1 cluster.

You can install all the instances on all the nodes and control the placement by configuring preferred owners.